# Can the results in a cursor be used on a secondary cursor query?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm having trouble figuring the correct way to use the results from cursor1 in cursor2. Can this be done? I had read that they can be stored in a declared VARCHAR(8000), however that throws an incorrect type error. My secondary question is, if those results can be stored, can they hold multiple columns/rows? I'm not very familiar with DB2, so any help from you pros would be appreciated.

Here's what it looks like in the code:

```
     BEGIN
     DECLARE v_type VARCHAR(8000);
     DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT type FROM vehicles;
     DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE type LIKE v_type;

     OPEN cursor1
     FETCH cursor1 INTO v_type;
     CLOSE cursor1;
     OPEN cursor2;
     END
     @
```

Lastly, is there any way to test a cursor for no results? Ideally through an "if" statement. Please feel free to correct any other issues in my syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will a `JOIN` not work?  What about something like the following:

```
DECLARE Manufactured_Vehicle CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT <list columns in manufacturers>
FROM manufacturers
JOIN vehicles
  ON vehicles.type = manufacturers.v_type -- whatever the relationship is
```

Storing the result in that fashion doesn't make any sense.

Also, what are you attempting to do in general?  What I mean is, cursors are often considered 'hacks', when a result-set may get to be too large - SQL is designed to work in a 'set-based' manner, not row-by-row.